# Select IDs which have different values across two columns

Tags: sql

my table looks the following:

```
EAN | Country | Status
1   | Germany | A
1   | France  | B
1   | Spain   | A
2   | Germany | A
2   | France  | A
2   | Spain   | A
```

I need every ID which Status is "A" in at least one country but is not in at least one other.

In this example the result should contain ID 1 because it has the status "A" in Germany and Spain but not in France.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS, and edit your Q to include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a *self join*:

```
select distinct main.EAN
  from [table] main
  join [table] sub
    on main.EAN = sub.EAN and
       main.Country <> sub.Country and
       main.Status <> sub.Status
```

`[table]` has to be replaced with your actual table's name. This should give you the desired results.

Comment: Awesome, simple yet functional... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just added the `distinct` key words to avoid duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

Using a subselect, you can do the following:

```
select
  EAN
from
  (
    select
      EAN,
      sum(case when Status = "A" then 1 else 0 end) statusA,
      sum(case when Status <> "A" then 1 else 0 end) statusOther
    from
      statuses
    group by
      EAN
  ) summary
where
  summary.statusA > 0 and
  summary.statusOther > 0
```

See an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31b6a/1).